# Событие на программное изменение данных в ячейки с формулой

Tags: vba

VBA Excel. как отследить событие программного изменения данных в зависимой ячейке?

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду, что изменяется состояние некоей ячейки RmCn, что через цепь формул изменит значение ячейки RxCy, и именно это изменение надо ловить - то надо просто использовать Worksheet_Change, который вызывается ПОСЛЕ выполнения всех каскадных вычислений:

```
Dim OldVal As Variant
Const CheckAddr as string = "Ы0"

Sub Worksheet_Change()
If Range(CheckAddr).Value <> OldVal Then
    msgbox CheckAddr & " cell changed." & vbNewLine & _
           "Old value: " & OldVal & vbNewLine & _
           "New value: " & Range(CheckAddr).Value
    OldVal = Range(CheckAddr).Value
End If
End Sub
```

Если тестируемых ячеек несколько - то OldVal делаем коллекцией, адреса ячеек == ключ, значение в ячейках == значение. Инициализируем, скажем, в Workbook_Load. И организуем цикл ForEach для проверки всех элементов коллекции на изменённость.